# How is InverseErf related to the inverse normal distribution?

Tags: distributions, inverse-function

The inverse function of the standard normal cdf is

`f[x_] := InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]`

I also have

`g[x_] := InverseErf[x]`

These two should be essentially the same but the domain of `f[x]` is `[0,1]` while the domain of `g[x]` is `[-1,1]`. How exactly are the two connected? It is not `f[x] = g[2x-1]`.

Comment: It should be `g[x_]:=-Sqrt[2] InverseErf[1 - 2 x]`

Comment: Thank you - I can accept it if you write it as an answer! Also, it is [2x -1] not [1-2x]

Comment: Not quite true.  If you use `2x-1` you'll need to remove the minus sign.  However, now that you mention it, `Sqrt[2] InverseErf[2 x - 1]` is a nicer form (with "nicer form" being in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use 2 unverified (but I think true) replacements:

```
FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]],
  Assumptions -> 0 <= x <= 1] /. InverseErfc[s_] -> InverseErf[1 - s]
(* -Sqrt[2] InverseErf[1 - 2 x] *)
```

This can be made into a nicer form as you mentioned:

```
% /. InverseErf[z_] -> -InverseErf[-z]
(* Sqrt[2] InverseErf[-1 + 2 x] *)
```